# Send Email Using PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to Send Email via gmail or yahoo host using PL_SQL, i searched in google and find SMT.Mail package but it did't work for me,  Please any one can guide me how will i achieve this goal ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE 
      send_mail (sender    IN VARCHAR2, 
                 recipient IN VARCHAR2, 
                 message   IN VARCHAR2, 
                 nStatus   OUT NUMBER) 
IS 
    mailhost    VARCHAR2(30) := 'smtp.gmail.com '; -- host mail addr 
    mail_conn  utl_smtp.connection; 
BEGIN 
    nStatus := 0; 
    mail_conn := utl_smtp.open_connection(mailhost, 25); 
    utl_smtp.helo(mail_conn, mailhost); 
    utl_smtp.mail(mail_conn, sender); 
    utl_smtp.rcpt(mail_conn, recipient); 
    utl_smtp.data(mail_conn, message); 
    utl_smtp.quit(mail_conn); 
EXCEPTION 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN 
        nStatus := SQLCODE; 
END send_mail;
```

when i test this procedure I get: `ORA-29278: SMTP transient error: 421 Service not available`

Comment: What so you mean by "it did't work for me"? What is the error you get? Please show some of your code.

Comment: And what is the error message?

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit this is error when i test this procedure: ORA-29278: SMTP transient error: 421 Service not available

Answer (score 2):

You missed your authentication at the server, see [AUTH Function and Procedure](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_smtp.htm#ARPLS72085)

However, I do not know whether gmail allows to use port 25 which is not secure by default.

Answer (score 2):

My experience has been that the utl_mail package is much easier to use. Here is a silly example:

```
BEGIN
   UTL_MAIL.send (sender     => 'bighearted@somewhere.com'
                , recipients => 'receiver@footballreceiver.com'
                , subject    => 'Goofy Messages'
                , MESSAGE    => 'Please don''t send any more goofy messages'
                , mime_type  => 'text/html; charset=us-ascii');
 END;
```

You must set the system parameter smtp_out_server to the name of your email server.

With Oracle 11G R2 and beyond, you must set up the proper access control list (ACL) for this to work. This is the code that I use to do so.

```
DECLARE
   -- ACL name to be used for email access reuse the same value for all 
   -- future calls
   l_acl         VARCHAR2 (30) := 'utl_smtp.xml';
   -- Oracle user to be given permission to send email
   l_principal   VARCHAR2 (30) := 'CEAADMIN';
   -- Name of email server
   g_mailhost    VARCHAR2 (60) := 'mail.yourserver.com';
   l_cnt         INTEGER;

   PROCEDURE validate_smtp_server
   AS
      l_value       v$parameter.VALUE%TYPE;
      l_parameter   v$parameter.name%TYPE := 'smtp_out_server';
   BEGIN

      SELECT VALUE
        INTO l_value
        FROM v$parameter
       WHERE name = l_parameter;

      IF l_value IS NULL
      THEN
         raise_application_error (
            -20001
          ,    'Oracle parameter '
            || l_parameter
            || ' has not been set'
            || UTL_TCP.crlf
            || 'it s/b mail.yourserver.com'
         );
      END IF;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('parameter ' || l_parameter || ' value is ' ||     l_value);

   END validate_smtp_server;

   PROCEDURE create_if_needed (p_acl IN VARCHAR2)
   AS
      l_cnt   INTEGER;
   BEGIN

      SELECT COUNT (*) c
        INTO l_cnt
        FROM dba_network_acls a
       WHERE SUBSTR (acl, INSTR (acl, '/', -1) + 1) = p_acl;

      IF l_cnt = 0
      THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('creating acl ' || p_acl);
         DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.create_acl (
            acl         => p_acl
          , description => 'Allow use of utl_smtp'
          , principal   => l_principal
          , is_grant    => TRUE
          , privilege   => 'connect'
         );

         DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.assign_acl (acl => p_acl, HOST => g_mailhost);
         COMMIT;
      ELSE
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (p_acl || ' acl already exists');
      END IF;

   END create_if_needed;

   PROCEDURE add_if_needed (
      p_principal   IN VARCHAR2
    , p_acl         IN VARCHAR2
   )
   AS
      l_cnt   INTEGER;
   BEGIN

      SELECT COUNT (*) c
        INTO l_cnt
        FROM dba_network_acl_privileges
       WHERE SUBSTR (acl, INSTR (acl, '/', -1) + 1) = p_acl
         AND principal = p_principal;

      IF l_cnt = 0
      THEN
         DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.add_privilege (
            acl       => 'utl_smtp.xml'
          , principal => p_principal
          , is_grant  => TRUE
          , privilege => 'connect'
         );
         COMMIT;
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('access to ' || p_acl || ' added for ' ||     p_principal);
      ELSE
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (p_principal || ' already has access to ' || p_acl);
      END IF;

   END add_if_needed;
BEGIN

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'grant execute on utl_mail to ' || l_principal;

   create_if_needed (p_acl => l_acl);
   add_if_needed (p_principal => l_principal, p_acl => l_acl);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Verification SQL:');
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('    SELECT * FROM dba_network_acls;');
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('    SELECT * FROM dba_network_acl_privileges;');
   COMMIT;
   validate_smtp_server;
END;
```

Comment: Hi @brian-leach, i'm trying the above mentioned script but i'm getting the error `PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN' must be declared`, probably due to the lack of grants to `DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN`, would it be possible to run this using another user? thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I have been on holiday for the Holy Days. Someone with DBA authority will have to run this script for you.