# creating a oracle trigger for sending mail after insert data in the table

Tags: c#, oracle

i am creating a oracle trigger for sending mail after insert or update data in database table
but there is a error occured

```
`ORA-24247: network access denied by access control list (ACL)
`ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_TCP", line 17`
`ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_TCP", line 246`
`ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 127`
`ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_SMTP", line 150`
`ORA-06512: at "TEST.SCRIPT_MAIL", line 9`
`ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'TEST.SCRIPT_MAIL'
```

i am using this code

```
`CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TEST.SCRIPT_MAIL 
AFTER INSERT 
ON TEST.PARTY_EMAIL 
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  v_From      VARCHAR2(80) := 'from@abc.in';
  v_Recipient VARCHAR2(80) := 'to@abcd.in';
  v_Subject   VARCHAR2(80) := 'test subject';
  v_Mail_Host VARCHAR2(30) := '<my domain>';
  v_Mail_Conn utl_smtp.Connection;
  crlf        VARCHAR2(2)  := chr(13)||chr(10);
BEGIN
 v_Mail_Conn := utl_smtp.Open_Connection(v_Mail_Host, 587);
 utl_smtp.Helo(v_Mail_Conn, v_Mail_Host);
 utl_smtp.Mail(v_Mail_Conn, v_From);
 utl_smtp.Rcpt(v_Mail_Conn, v_Recipient);
 utl_smtp.Data(v_Mail_Conn,
   'Date: '   || to_char(sysdate, 'Dy, DD Mon YYYY hh24:mi:ss') || crlf ||
   'From: '   || v_From || crlf ||
   'Subject: '|| v_Subject || crlf ||
   'To: '     || v_Recipient || crlf ||
   crlf ||
   'some message text'|| crlf ||    -- Message body
   'more message text'|| crlf
 );
utl_smtp.Quit(v_mail_conn);
EXCEPTION`
 WHEN utl_smtp.Transient_Error OR utl_smtp.Permanent_Error then
   raise_application_error(-20000, 'Unable to send mail', TRUE);
END;`
```

how to solve it 
please help

Comment: check network firewall..... User Permissions

Comment: how to check network firewall ...........in my system

Comment: You can try to disable you windows firewall temporarily, as long as your data above is good and working.

Comment: my window firewall status is off

Comment: Google for Oracle ACL settings.

Answer (score 0):

try to see a reference here:

Cause:

```
No access control list (ACL) has been assigned to the target host or the 
privilege necessary to access the target host has not been granted to the 
user in the access control list.
```

Action:

```
Ensure that an access control list (ACL) has been assigned to the target 
host and the privilege necessary to access the target host has been granted 
to the user.
```

[network_access_denied_by_access_control_list](http://dba-oracle.com/t_ora_24247_network_access_denied_by_access_control_list_tips.htm)

Comment: principal => 'SYS',

Comment: privilege => 'connect'

Comment: i have code for access control list .............but i don't know how to set it's value        `principle=>'what is here value'` and privilege=

Comment: `privilege=>'what is here value'`

Comment: I am not an oracle expert but i'm just trying to help your problem. take a look at this.. https://www.pythian.com/blog/setting-up-network-acls-in-oracle-11g-for-dummies/

Comment: ORA-29278: SMTP transient error: 421 Service not available

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41377078/ora-29278-smtp-transient-error-service-not-available-when-running-utl-mail